# Restrict user access to admin panel

Tags: php

I am trying to add some security to my website which has an admin panel and a user page. So far my security has code which sends the user back to the login page if the user tries to access a page through the url. However, there is still one problem that remains. If I login as a user, the user can access the admin-panel. This should not be able to occur since it is an user not an admin.

Here is my code so far:

```
<?php

session_start();

if (!$_SESSION['username']) {
    header("Location: login.php");
}
```

Can anyone help me by telling me how to implement a piece of code that restricts the user to accessing the admin-panel.

Comment: Is admin a role or is there only *one* specific admin?

Comment: Admin is a role it is in my table.

Comment: Would I use a session? Or would I check if the user is an admin or user with a variable like $row. If I do this I don't know how I restrict it going to the specific admin-panel folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a column for Access on your table for accounts, if the user is Standard User or System admin. then in your php code store the access in a session variable.

```
if($_SESSION['access']=='admin'){
     header("Location: admin-panel.php");
}else{
     header("Location: somewhereelse.php");
}
```

Comment: use the access column to restrict the movements of your standard user. Hope it will help you :)

Comment: This would work but is there any possible way to restrict a whole folder?

Comment: yes you can. just create on your admin a settings that restricts the user on what modules that she/he can access

Comment: I have another question, how would I initiate the session so it would have two options.

Comment: What do you mean on Initiate?

Comment: like start it such as $_SESSION['username'] = $username;

Comment: ahhh. you can put it on your login code. if the a user successfully login get its access then store it on a session variable

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227312/discussion-between-pro-gamer-and-ainz).

Answer (score 2):

add flags/permissions/roles to your user table then check if the current logged in user has a permission to access to page.

A simple approach for this is sample:

**admin_page.php** so we suppose that the user can access to this page is only admin

then in your back-end you can check the permission this way

```
if($user->role != "admin")
{
 // return a message here or redirect them to some error page
}
```

Comment: Sorry I am not familiar with -> what does that mean exactly?

Comment: I am sorry, but that is object operator a way to call a property in an object. if this is so new to you then you can follow the answer of @Ainz

Comment: so role is an object? interesting

Comment: well we can say the role is the property and the user is the object
take note that the user is not a predefined object in PHP, the sample that I give is only a snippet. I am sorry if this confused you